# How to set in java program that is registered on oracle db- character set for Polish sings

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Im running a program in java, registered in oracleDB.
I have a 11.0.2.4 version of oracle DB.
What im trying to achieve is to import files from some folder with polish sings.
So far program is importing data, but it changes the polish sings.
Im not into java very much, but i read that i have to set:

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("Polish", "Poland", "pl_PL"));
```

Which i already did, and it is not working.
Entire program looks like (from PLSQL) :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED SCHEMA."DirListClass" AS
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DirListClass
{
public static void getList(String directory)
                   throws SQLException
{
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("Polish", "Poland", "pl_PL"));
    File path = new File( directory );
    String[] list = path.list();
    String element;

    File fileObject;
    long length;
    String dateStr, type;
    Date now = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy H:m:s");

    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
        element = list[i];
        fileObject = new File(directory + File.separatorChar + list[i]);
        length = fileObject.length();
        if (fileObject.isDirectory()) {
          type = "d";
        } else if (fileObject.isFile()) {
          type = "f";
        } else {
          type = "?";
        }

        java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date(fileObject.lastModified());
        dateStr = format.format(d);

        #sql { INSERT INTO dir_list(filename,length, mod_date, type)
               VALUES (:element, :length, to_date(:dateStr,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), :type) };
    }
}
}
```

For example:
Instead of import: "ż"
It imports: "Ĺş"
Any ideas?

Comment: What value gets printed before insert within Java? Possibly the character set is different in the database. For Oracle database Polish character set is ISO 8859-2 (Eastern European). If the issue is within database then setting the nls_characterset should fix the issue.

Comment: @VN'sCorner can i set in in java? Could you give some code that is already working?
I've been testing it thru alter session, but it didnt worked for me- i could only set NLS_LANGUAGE and NLS_TERRITORY in that way

Comment: Are the values getting printed appropriate with Java, i.e. before insert. This is to understand if the rootcause is in JAVA or in Oracle. The fix will hugely depend on diagnosing where the problem is? You may try to set NLS_LANGUAGE to using ,alter session set nls_language ='EE8PC852'(Polish Language).  I have not done that in JAVA but in oracle for oracle stored object.

Comment: They print propely in Java so i guess its something with nls.

Comment: i added an convert code, that is actually converting any non ascii character to polish nls that you mentioned (EE8PC852), and now instead of strange letters in the topic, i get 'z', but I should get 'ż'. What is more i tested convertion code with polish letters like 'ż' and it returns 'z' too. 
Code looks like:    

 /* Changing nonAscii characters code:
     `column_name:=REGEXP_REPLACE (
         CONVERT (
             column_name,
             'US7ASCII',
             'EE8PC852'),
          '[^!@/\.,;:<>#$%&()_=[:alnum:][:blank:]]');`